# Pass Latex elements inside Table in Manim TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tex found

Tags: manim

Manim can take Latex for row_labels, column_labels but not for elements inside table. It seems to be able to accept string only.

Take the following for example:

```
from manim import *

class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t3 = Table(
            [["y","2"],
            ["z","4"]],
            row_labels=[Tex(r"$\frac{a}{b}$"), Text("R2")],
        )
        self.add(t3)
        
TableExamples().render()
```

It works successfully and the first row_lable comes out fraction(a/b) [image: Manim output image]

But if I try to insert Latex for elements inside table (in place of y in the following example),

```
from manim import *

class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t3 = Table(
            [[Tex(r"$\frac{a}{b}$"),"2"],
            ["z","4"]],
            row_labels=[Tex(r"$\frac{a}{b}$"), Text("R2")],
        )
        self.add(t3)
        
TableExamples().render()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tex found
```

Is there a way to get around this?
I tried

> r"$\frac{a}{b}$"

> "$\frac{a}{b}$"

> str(Tex(r"$\frac{a}{b}$"))

and different variations of the above. None of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different `Table` objects defined in Manim. The plain `Table` only accepts strings or numeric values as elements. The `MobjectTable` accepts any Mobject, for example also a `MathTex` object. The disadvantage is that you then have to set the Mobject for all elements:

```py
class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t3 = MobjectTable(
            [[MathTex(r"\frac{a}{b}"),MathTex(r"2")],
            [MathTex(r"z"),MathTex(r"4")]],
            row_labels=[Tex(r"$\frac{a}{b}$"), Text("R2")],
        )
        self.add(t3)
```

[image]

You can also for the `Table` object redefine the `element_to_mobject=` parameter and set it to `MathTex`

```py
class TableExamples(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        t3 = Table(
            [[r"\frac{a}{b}",r"2"],
            [r"z",r"4"]],
            row_labels=[MathTex(r"\frac{a}{b}"), Text("R2")],
            element_to_mobject=MathTex
        )
        self.add(t3)
```

[image]

For more details have a look in [the documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.table.Table.html)

And if you want to [find more resources for learning Manim come to the Discord server](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim)